# Losing JPA connection after some idle time

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I do lose the connection to my database every time the API is idle for some time (the time cannot be defined precisely. It can happen after idle time of just some seconds, sometimes idle time after minutes, sometimes even right after jetty restart). This issue is reproducible on different machines, so I recon it has nothing to do with the mysql database directly.

The exception thrown can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/raw/c80ccb7748f2e1dcf7af/0bf51ecefa0bf90045076b481a8bafdf7041c277/gistfile1.txt)

The database configuration is based upon hibernate and spring:

```
 <!-- c3p0 of version 0.9.2.1 (current stable) -->
 <!-- spring data: 1.2.0.RELEASE -->
 <!-- mysql connector: 5.1.18 -->
 <!-- hibernate: 4.1.9.FINAL --> 
 <bean id="basisDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="86400" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="de.yourdelivery.data.*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

the Database connection and driver is a followed:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/xxx?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

it does not even work with extending the jdbc.url by

```
&autoReconnect=true&autoReconnectForPools=true
```

I use OpenSessionInView Pattern to lazy load all my needed relations during dozer mapping (I know it is deemed to be an anti pattern, but it worked fine so far so currently not blaming it on that pattern)

Mysql `wait_timeout` is set to 28800

Startup log for C3PO looks like that

> 13:34:54,687  INFO PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:177 - Loading
>   properties file from file
>   [/opt/jetty/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/classes/properties/customer.fidelity.points.properties]
>   13:34:54,687  INFO PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:177 - Loading
>   properties file from file
>   [/opt/jetty/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/classes/properties/application.properties]
>   13:34:54,687  INFO PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:177 - Loading
>   properties file from file
>   [/opt/jetty/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/classes/properties/restapi.properties]
>   13:34:54,688  INFO PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:177 - Loading
>   properties file from file
>   [/opt/jetty/jetty-distribution-8.1.8.v20121106/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/classes/properties/database.properties]
>   13:34:54,823  INFO MLog:80 - MLog clients using log4j logging.
>   13:34:54,883  INFO C3P0Registry:204 - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built
>   21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10] 13:34:55,111  INFO
>   XmlWebApplicationContext:1350 - Bean 'deDataSource' of type [class
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource] is not eligible for getting
>   processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for
>   auto-proxying) 13:34:55,148  INFO XmlWebApplicationContext:1350 - Bean
>   'plDataSource' of type [class
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource] is not eligible for getting
>   processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for
>   auto-proxying) 13:34:55,150  INFO XmlWebApplicationContext:1350 - Bean
>   'dataSource' of type [class
>   de.yourdelivery.data.routing.DomainRouting] is not eligible for
>   getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible
>   for auto-proxying) 13:34:55,167  INFO XmlWebApplicationContext:1350 -
>   Bean
>   'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#24bb6086'
>   of type [class
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] is not
>   eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example:
>   not eligible for auto-proxying) 13:34:55,213  INFO
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:264 - Building JPA container
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 13:34:55,332  INFO
>   Version:37 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
>   13:34:55,338  INFO Version:41 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core
>   {4.1.9.Final} 13:34:55,341  INFO Environment:239 - HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found 13:34:55,342  INFO Environment:342 -
>   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist 13:34:55,361  INFO
>   Ejb3Configuration:527 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>           name: default
>           ...] 13:34:55,795  INFO ConnectionProviderInitiator:188 - HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider:
>   org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
>   13:34:55,880  INFO AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:462 - Initializing
>   c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [
>   acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay
>   -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0,
>   connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName ->
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName ->
>   1hge17b8s1e4h6uz10tbcor|3efe0ce9, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces
>   -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions ->
>   false, identityToken -> 1hge17b8s1e4h6uz10tbcor|3efe0ce9,
>   idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl ->
>   jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.10:3306/xxxx?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 86400, maxIdleTime
>   -> 600, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5,
>   numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0,
>   preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=*****,
>   password=*****}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin ->
>   false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout
>   -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ] 13:34:56,086  INFO Dialect:123 - HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 13:34:56,095  INFO
>   LobCreatorBuilder:120 - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation
>   as createClob() method threw error :
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 13:34:56,108  INFO
>   TransactionFactoryInitiator:73 - HHH000268: Transaction strategy:
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
>   13:34:56,112  INFO ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:48 - HHH000397: Using
>   ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 13:34:56,149  INFO Version:24 - Hibernate
>   Validator 4.2.0.Final 13:34:56,916  INFO XmlWebApplicationContext:1350
>   - Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is
>   not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
>   example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

So why is the application losing its connection during idle time?

Comment: why do I loose my connection? I recon you can imagine that is not a wanted behavior of the application :)

Comment: "for some time" what time do you mean?

Comment: sadly that is exactly the point, that the time cannot be defined precisely. Sometimes it happens right after starting the jetty server, then all further request are going through just fine. Once no further requests are coming in there is a high a chance of the error to occure. But I can wait for a minute, do another request just fine or wait just for some seconds and it breaks...

Comment: but you precisely killing the cons after 24rs of life.

Comment: so, does it answer your question?

Comment: not at all... as I mentioned that error happens sometimes right after jetty start, so there sure isn't any connections already 24h old

Comment: Are you sure that your validation query is executed successfuly? Also, could you check that connections will be returned to your data source?    You may need to inform your CDI platform that you use a connection pool.

Comment: you mentioned that you can replicate the error on different machines... but are you still trying to connect to the same db instance from these other machines?

Comment: no all different physical databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem

It can happen due to possibly multiple reasons. your app server is losing connections to your DB. It is hard to tell looking at the logs that only connections which are idle are the only one which are getting killed. 
Your DB server might be not allocating connections. I hope you have checked your DB logs for errors.  How you are handling transactions in your services ? Are you using spring transactions ?

It’s a good idea always to specify destroy-method if you are using external connection pool provider , so as to shutdown the data source immediately when the spring application shuts down

```
<bean id="basisDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

Change the following in your c3p0 pool settings

Take two approaches 
Remove `maxConnectionAge` & `maxIdleTime`

Test by changing below two parameters , they are expensive in terms of performance hit

```
testConnectionOnCheckout =true 
preferredTestQuery =SELECT 1
```

In case if you are able to resolve it using the above settings

Change the above settings to below as the below is less expensive in terms of performance hit

```
idleConnectionTestPeriod – 30 
preferredTestQuery =SELECT 1
```

Post your findings

Comment: that is some helpful advise, will try that out today!

Comment: it looks like to have solved the issue, still wondering why this actually happens. I will test it for some more hours though

Comment: Thats good. Keep posted about your findings. How do you manage your transactions ?

Comment: I would suppose not at all, since I have not implemented anything related to transaction management

Answer (score 0):

You need periodic connection testing so that network appliances like firewalls don't kill the connection. All the details here: [C3P0 configuration](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing)

Comment: mh ok I could implement such, but I more like to know why the connection seems to be killed? It is even reproducable on a local machine listening on the localhost where no strict firewall settings apply. The behavior even occurs on a fresh os install (e.g. debian)

Answer (score 0):

I would check

- whether mysql is not closing the connections from its side - what is the value of wait_timeout in your my.cnf?
- if hibernate is using its own internal connection pool , you should have hibernate.connection.provider_class set, can you post your hibernate configuration? see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e150

Comment: wait_timeout: 28800 and configuration added to question

Comment: Could you post also hibernate startup log? And addin logging to c3po would be helful too: log4j.logger.com.mchange=debug

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, first adding a destroy method in your application beans configuration as suggested by 'user395072'

Other than that, check the mySQL connection and server configuration properties.  I believe, mySQL has some 1000 queries default limit (I saw this on mySQL 5.24).  Disconnection is, to my best guess, happening at the mySQL tier - where the server might be 'thinking' that the connection is no longer needed.  If there was a fixed time-frame to 'disconnect' or any user event associated with the disconnections then there would have been a possibility of application configuration issues.

In your case, I strongly think, it is the database server configuration.